# iOS - UINavigationBar - flat style buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wanted to know how to implement Skype-like buttons in UINavigationBar that would give a flat feeling but subtly embossed like the "Edit" and "Lists" buttons in the screenshot below.

Should I create images, or is there any simple way of doing that in code or with a library?

[image: Skype Buttons]

Answer (score 3):

You need to create two images for normal state and for highlight, selected states. Then create UIButton with these two images and add this UIButton to UIBarButtonItem as customView. Then you can add your UIBarButtonItem to navigationBar. That's all.

Comment: Yes that is the simple image way, but how to scale with the size of the text? And keep the left arrow of the "back" button? I was wondering if there was a "magic" property I was missing since many application share this style.

Comment: `UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton"]   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];` And for text shift use UIEdgeInsetsMake for UIButton.title look at UIButton reference.

Comment: Skype is definitely using a UIBarButtonItem subclass.

Comment: They use drawRect: method or use images?